# How to execute a gradle external task (Exec) in background?

Tags: gradle, jetty, gulp

I'm using gradle and gulp to build and launch my JEE web application that is based on JDK6+, and the web container is Jetty.

Gulp is used to process static resource, such as concat and minify javascript/css files. Also, there is a `watch` task in my gulp script, it is used to watch static file changes and rebuild them automatically.

So to launch the application in Jetty, i need to do following things:

1. Build static resource using gulp `[gulp task: build]`.
2. Watch static file changes `[gulp task: watch]`, i don't call this gulp task directly, it is call by a gradle task via *Exec* class `[gradle task: watch]`.
3. Build my java code and launch Jetty `[gradle task: jettyRun]`.

Since i added the gradle task `watch` as a dependency of `jettyRun` task, so i though i only need to call `gradle jettyRun` from command line, my application will be launched. But the result is not same as i expected.

---

Following is my script files:

***build.gradle***

```
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'jetty'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

// omit the dependencies here

task watch(type: Exec){
    workingDir "${projectDir}"
    // Pass build type to npm and gulp.
    commandLine "gulp", "watch"
}
jettyRun.dependsOn watch
```

***gulpfile.js***

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
gulp.task('build', function(callback) {
    // removed the code to make this question as simple as possible.
    if (callback != null) callback();
});

gulp.task('watch', function(callback) {
    gulp.watch(['./src/static/**/*.js'], ['build']);
    if (callback != null) callback();
});
```

---

**The result:**

[image: The execute result]

**Question:**

Now, the process hungs when excutes the `gradle watch` task, there is no change to execute `jettyRun` task for gradle. I know this hang is caused by the watch process launched by gulp, because it is watching file changes. But i hope that gradle just only launch the gulp watch process and return immediately to execute the next `jettyRun` task!

How to do this? Also, i want to see the output of watch task from stdout.

I know there is a ProcessBuilder in java, i have tried it, but it doesn't work. Maybe I have done something wrong. :(

[Download all files](https://www.dropbox.com/s/km5b4ln9xhtd1g0/gradle-gulp.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864205/run-javaexec-task-in-background-and-then-terminate-when-build-completes) help? Or [this plugin](https://github.com/marcoVermeulen/gradle-spawn-plugin)?

Comment: I don't think watch task should be part of build, it can be called once and run in background all the time. I think it's better to separate the watch task and put it into some sever startup script.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `ProcessBuilder` to launch an external process in the background and let gradle continue with other tasks. Also `finalizedBy` can be used to stop watching  when `runJetty` has been completed.

```
task watch {
    doFirst {
        println("Start watching")
        ext.process = new ProcessBuilder()
            .directory(projectDir)
            .command("gulp", "watch")
            .start()
    }
}

task stopWatching {
    doFirst {
        println("Stop watching")
        if (tasks.watch.process != null) {
            tasks.watch.process.destroy()
        }
    }
}

task runJetty {
    finalizedBy stopWatching
}
```