# Run Server when Integration Testing with Gradle

Tags: testing, gradle, integration, kryonet

I've developed a client-server-architecture using Kryonet and Gradle with roughly the following structure

- Parent project X, containing projects A and B
- Project A (server)
- Project B (client), containing integration and unit test classes

Now whenever I'm running the goal 'integrationTest' on project B (or project X, if that was easier), I'd like the server to get started in advance so that the integration tests won't fail.

This is what I've got so far in the build.gradle of project B - it doesn't run the server, though:

```
task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDir
    classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most concise answer I've found to this is to use ProcessBuilder to run the server in the background, as detailed in the answer to this question: 
[How to execute a gradle external task (Exec) in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31189351/how-to-execute-a-gradle-external-task-exec-in-background?rq=1)

In you case I'd make a task in parent project X that launches a separate gradle build (using the above) to run the server and then runs the client.