# Gradle : create custom task to run 3 spring boot apps

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle-task

I have to create custom task in gradle to run 3 spring boot apps, but first 'dependsOn' block other commands from my task and only one app starts.

```
task startApps(type: Exec) 
{
    dependsOn 'modules::module_1::bootRun'
    dependsOn 'modules::module_2::bootRun'
    dependsOn 'modules::module_3::bootRun'
}
```

Anyone know how to do this ? Help me ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your task is running on a single thread.  To get all three apps to run simultaneously you'll need to run them asynchronously in parallel.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47202438/2719299) explains how to do it programmatically using a ProcessBuilder.  Another option if you have a multi-project build is to tell [Gradle to run in parallel](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:parallel_execution) via the --parallel flag.