# Asynchronous gradle copy task?

Tags: asynchronous, gradle, groovy

So I create an archive, say a war, and then I want another copy with a different name for convenience. Thing is that I don't want that copy task to slow down the rest of this rather large build. Possible to execute it asynchronously? If so, how?

Comment: No idea if this actually works, but you could give it a try: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38528039/745574

Comment: Really nice @RaGe, thanks for finding this!

Comment: I think I have this working. Thanks guys. :-) Do you want to post as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import java.util.concurrent.*
...
def es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
...
war {
...
doLast{
        es.submit({
            copy {
                from destinationDir.absolutePath + File.separator + "$archiveName"
                into destinationDir
                rename "${archiveName}", "${baseName}.${extension}"

            }
        } as Callable)
    }
}
```

Comment: Will that do it? It works. The file gets copied but IDK how to test to see if it's actually an asynchronous copy.

Comment: The doLast keeps it from firing off before other things happen. Like the creation of the war that needs copying.

Comment: Reading the above, I've just answered my own question.

Answer (score 4):

In some cases, it's very handy to use [parallel execution feature](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:parallel_execution) for this. It works only with multiproject builds (the tasks you want to execute parallel must be in separate projects).

```
project('first') {
  task copyHugeFile(type: Copy) {
    from "path/to/huge/file"
    destinationDir buildDir
    doLast {
      println 'The file is copied'
    }
  }
}

project('second') {
  task printMessage1 << {
    println 'Message1'
  }

  task printMessage2 << {
    println 'Message2'
  }
}

task runAll {
  dependsOn ':first:copyHugeFile'
  dependsOn ':second:printMessage1'
  dependsOn ':second:printMessage2'
}
```

The default output:

```
$ gradle runAll

:first:copyHugeFile
The file is copied
:second:printMessage1
Message1
:second:printMessage2
Message2
:runAll
```

The output with `--parallel`:

```
$ gradle runAll --parallel

Parallel execution is an incubating feature.
:first:copyHugeFile
:second:printMessage1
Message1
:second:printMessage2
Message2
The file is copied
:runAll
```

Comment: We can't use it due to some tech debt with dbUnit. The thing is that there's really never a reason the file can't be copied in parallel so I prefer to write it so that it always is.