# Parallel execution in Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, ant

I am migrating my build from Ant to Gradle and trying to rewrite this code block:

```
 <parallel>
            <exec executable="npm">
                <arg value="run"/>
                <arg value="dev"/>
            </exec>
            <java className="foo.bar.Launcher" fork="true">
                <classpath>
                    <path refid="project.classpath"/>
                </classpath>
            </java>
 </parallel>
```

But I hadn't found something similar to parallel tag, only solutions with Java concurrency or some other workarounds. Does Gradle have some proper way to execute something in parallel without workarounds?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38905329/asynchronous-gradle-copy-task/38915824

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that executing tasks (in the same project) in parallel is at best an incubating feature (or not yet available) ([see doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:parallel_execution)).

However, in your case, note that Gradle contains an Ant Builder. Because you are not trying to run *tasks* in parallel, it might be a straight-ahead port. ([Here is a discussion](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-use-ants-parallel-target/6720) of using `ant.parallel`.)

To illustrate, consider this shell-script, `wait.sh`:

```
sleep $1 
echo $2 >> wait.log
```

And the following tasks:

```
task doItSerial << {
    ant.exec(executable: "${projectDir}/wait.sh") {
        arg(value: 10)
        arg(value: "TRACER A")
    }
    ant.exec(executable: "${projectDir}/wait.sh") {
        arg(value: 10)
        arg(value: "TRACER B")
    }
}

task doItParallel << {
    ant.parallel {
        ant.exec(executable: "${projectDir}/wait.sh") {
            arg(value: 10)
            arg(value: "TRACER A")
        }
        ant.exec(executable: "${projectDir}/wait.sh") {
            arg(value: 10)
            arg(value: "TRACER B")
        }
    }
}
```

In my experimentation, `doItSerial` takes 20 seconds; `doItParallel` takes 10 seconds, as we would anticipate.

Comment: Simple solution are often the best !!! Thx for this simple idea with is better imho than https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-you-run-multiple-javaexec-tasks-in-parallel/7309